# How to increase aws amplify request/response timeout?

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I have my NextJS frontend hosted in AWS Amplify. After a few seconds, I keep getting a 504 Gateway Timeout Error. My backend API (hosted elsewhere in ECS) is quite slow, so I want to know what the default AWS Amplify request/response timeout is, and how I can increase it. I am NOT looking for build timeout. This is runtime timeout. The documentation seems lacking in explaining this. Thanks.

Comment: I checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76563090/how-to-increase-timeout-of-amplify-in-nextjs-504-code?rq=2, but there was no satisfactory response.

Answer (score 0):

If you call your back-end directly, like any 3rd party rest API, then you wouldn't be asking about the NextJS/amplify deployment, so I'll assume you're calling your back-end from within `/pages/api`.

When you do that yourAmplify deploys your /api code as Lambda@Edge. (Note: It may be deployed to a different region. I deploy to Ohio, but the Lambda@Edge is put into N. Virginia.) The Lambda will have a timeout of 30 seconds. You may be able to increase this manually. Lambda@Edge may have a max-timeout of 30 seconds.

Another issues is that the front-end calls the Lambda@Edge function via API Gateway, which has a 29 second timeout that cannot be increased.

If you're getting `504 timeout` or similar at about the 30 second mark, it's likely API GW.

How to fix? If your backend is slow, then the front-end API should just "initiate a job" and return quickly, then use a GQL subscription or polling to get the job completion event.

Comment: Thanks. So basically, short of polling or subscription, there is no way to handle a slow backend by increasing timeout parameters correct?

Comment: Correct. At least not that I'm aware of. Since you're using Amplify, you could `amplify add function` to add a Lambda. Have that lambda call your backend. Update the cloudformation (or use click-ops) to get a lambda-url for the lambda. Then you can poke the Lambda from your front-end via that URL (as opposed to using a GQL resolver which has another timeout). This bypasses API Gateway so you can have up to 15 minutes. Just beware ANYONE can poke that lambda, so do the necessary auth.